# Too Many Redirection in Nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx

I have a website(web server is nginx) with static(React JS & images) content with caching enabled & assume the URL of website is www.example.com, we are proxy passing /abc(.*) request on WordPress(web server is apache) website. Our WordPress URL(site & home) is www.example.com/abc/.

Now the scenarios are:

- www.example.com/abc/ is working as expected.
- www.example.com/abc is working for sometime & after that throwing the **too many redirections** error. After clearing the cache of www.example.com(React JS website), it is again started working &
  after sometime, again the same issue(too many redirections).

My assumptions are:

- No issue from ReactJS website web server configuration.
- The issue is with WP configuration.

**Nginx conf file partial snippet:**

```
 upstream wp-server {
                            server WP_SERVER max_fails=2 fail_timeout=20s;
                            server WP_SERVER max_fails=2 fail_timeout=20s;

     }

    server { 
                ....

               location ~* abc(.*) {
                proxy_pass http://wp-server;

                } 

}
```

No specific changes in apache conf & server name is www.example.com in conf.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add your nginx example.com config and Wordpress Rewrite config.

Comment: @Anuga Added nginx conf, will add apache as well

Answer (score 0):

I have troubleshot & fixed the issue. We were using the response cache plugin(due to some dependency) which was the culprit for this activity.